# Quartz Scheduler implementation

Tags: quartz-scheduler

What is the internal mechanism for persisting data using Quartz Scheduler?
I went through internet but didn't find clear description.
It would be great if you suggest the same to work in hibernate platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Quartz Scheduler in your project you should have a file for  its properties which is called `quartz.properties`. In this file you should determine your persistence mechanism by using parameter: `org.quartz.jobStore.class`
The value for this parameter can be the followings:

1. `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT`: it means that you want to persist in a database and transactions are managed by a container (Like Weblogic, JBoss, ...)
2. `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX`: it means that you want to persist in a database and transactions are NOT managed by a container. this option is used mostly when you run Quartz Scheduler as a standing alone application.
3. `org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore`: This option actually is not recommended in production environment because according this parameter Quartz persists jobs and triggers just in RAM!
4. `org.terracotta.quartz.TerracottaJobStore`: The last option is using Terracotta Server as your persistence unit, Quartz says that it is the fastest way.

I myself prefer first option, it is straightforward and more reliable I think.
You can read more about this configuration [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.2/html/qtz-all/#page/quartz-scheduler-webhelp%2Fto-quartz_scheduler_online_documentation_library.html%23).
And about hibernate, quartz will manage the persistence tasks, like rollback and persist, and you wont being involved in this process.